# Replace words of a sentence with formatted html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this string:

```
var text = "Altough I am the eldest son, they stil see me as kdi.";
```

and this array:

```
var errors = ["Altough", "stil", "kdi"];
```

I would like to replace the words in the sentence that are in the array, so the text would look like this:

```
<span class="error">Altough</span> I am the eldest son, they <span class="error">stil</span> see me as <span class="error">kdi</span>.
```

Do I have to use regex, or the javascript replace() function will do?

Comment: You should probably split the sentence into tokens first, then evaluate each token, then build up your annotated html string.  That way you won't suffer from the substring problem as easily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use regexp and replace :

```
var errors = ["Altough", "stil", "kdi"];
var regExp = new RegExp('\\b('+errors.join('|')+')\\b', 'gi');
var text = text.replace(regExp, '<span class="error">$1</span>');
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/uezjK/4/

Comment: This will flag words that contain the errors array as substrings.  For example, in "still" the "stil" will get flagged, which is probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: [@Chris is correct](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uezjK/2/); But, on the bright side: [`\b` can help](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uezjK/3/).

Comment: @ChrisFarmer thank for pointing it out, changed the expression!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Karl-Andre's answer, here is a way without regex (just to give you a different prospective):

```
var text = "Altough I am the eldest son, they stil see me as kdi.";
var errors = ["Altough", "stil", "kdi"];

for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
    var content = errors[i];
    text = text.replace(content, "<span class='error'>" + content + "</span>");
}
```

Here is a fiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/azMVk/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that doesn't fail for valid words which have substrings which are error words ("still" for example).

http://jsfiddle.net/uezjK/1/

```
var text = "Altough I am the eldest son, they stil see me as kdi. But I am still a kid."; 
var tokens = text.split(/\s+/);

var errors = ["Altough", "stil", "kdi"]; 
var html = "";

for (var i=0; i<tokens.length; i++) {
    var word = tokens[i].replace(/\W+/, '');
    if ($.inArray(word, errors) >= 0) {
        html += "<span class='error'>" + tokens[i] + "</span> "; 
    } else {
        html += tokens[i] + " ";
    } }

$('body').append(html)
```